# Calculating Pearson correlation

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I'm trying to calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient of two variables. These variables are to determine if there is a relationship between number of postal codes to a range of distances. So I want to see if the number of postal codes increases/decreases as the distance ranges changes.

I'll have one list which will count the number of postal codes within a distance range and the other list will have the actual ranges.

Is it ok to have a list that contain a range of distances? Or would it be better to have a list like this [50, 100, 500, 1000] where each element would then contain ranges up that amount. So for example the list represents up to 50km, then from 50km to 100km and so on.

Comment: @Krab Removed unnecessary information inline with SO policy, SO is a question and answer site so saying I would appreciate help is redundant, to say thanks you upvote and accept answer.. if you want more information on this read the faq and dig around on meta stackoverflow

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use scipy :

```
scipy.stats.pearsonr(x, y)
```

> Calculates a Pearson correlation coefficient and the p-value for testing non-correlation.
>
> The Pearson correlation coefficient measures the linear relationship between two datasets. Strictly speaking, Pearson’s correlation requires that each dataset be normally distributed. Like other correlation coefficients, this one varies between -1 and +1 with 0 implying no correlation. Correlations of -1 or +1 imply an exact linear relationship. Positive correlations imply that as x increases, so does y. Negative correlations imply that as x increases, y decreases.
>
> The p-value roughly indicates the probability of an uncorrelated system producing datasets that have a Pearson correlation at least as extreme as the one computed from these datasets. The p-values are not entirely reliable but are probably reasonable for datasets larger than 500 or so.
>
> Parameters :
>
> > x : 1D array
> >
> > y : 1D array the same length as x
>
> Returns :
>
> > (Pearson’s correlation coefficient, :
> >     2-tailed p-value)

Comment: Ok, so what matters more is that both the x and y arrays are of the same length. Then you are comparing elements x[i] with element y[i]?

Comment: yep. In your case, x should be equal to the distances considered, and y[i] should return the number of postal code at distances[i]. To see the actual computation for the Pearson : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949226/calculating-pearson-correlation-and-significance-in-python

Comment: Cool, so x[i] could mean up to that distance?

Comment: Yes, x[i] could mean up to that distance. If all the distances are computed from a particular starting point, then x[i] is just an area of that distance, and the corresponding y[i] would be how many postal codes are covered in that area.

Comment: Make sure that the arrays x and y have a mean of 0. Otherwise you will get an incorrect value.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `numpy`:

```
numpy.corrcoef(x, y)
```

which would give you a correlation matrix that looks like:

```
[[1          correlation(x, y)]
[correlation(y, x)          1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 val=Top15[['Energy Supply per Capita','Citable docs per Capita']].rank().corr(method='pearson')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.10 [correlation()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.correlation) function was added to the `statistics` module of the Python standard library, it can be directly used by importing the statistics module:

```
import statistics

statistics.correlation(words, views)
```