# Accurate p-value of Pearson correlation test with small samples?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, p-value, scipy.stats

To get [the correlation between two arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949282/2801037), I am using:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
x, y = [1, 2, 3], [1, 5, 7]
cor, p = pearsonr(x, y)
```

However, as stated in [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html#scipy.stats.pearsonr), "the p-values are not entirely reliable but are probably reasonable for datasets larger than 500 or so." So how can I get a p-value that is reasonable for small datasets?

**My temporary solution:**

After reading up on linear regression, I have come up with my own small script, which basically uses [Fischer transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Use_the_Fisher_transformation) to get the z-score, from which the p-value is calculated:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import zprob
n = len(x)
z = np.log((1+cor)/(1-cor))*0.5*np.sqrt(n-3))
p = zprob(-z)
```

It works. However, I am not sure if it is more reasonable than the p-value given by `pearsonr()`. Is there a Python module which already has this functionality? I have not been able to find it in [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) or [Statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/ipdirective/index.html).

**Edit to clarify:**

The dataset in my example is simplified. My real dataset is two arrays of 10-50 values.

Comment: I think this question is better fitted in cross validated.

Comment: A correlation over a sample size of 3 is not sensible...I usually want at least a pair of 50 values before thinking a correlation might be useful.

Comment: @Korem I did consider it, but posted it here instead as it mainly is a coding issue. However, I will move it there if no one can answer here.

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.stats.pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) now accepts an instance of [`scipy.stats.PermutationMethod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.PermutationMethod.html#scipy.stats.PermutationMethod) to be passed as its `method` argument. This allows you to perform an exact test of the null hypothesis that the observations in `x` and `y` were drawn from independent (and therefore uncorrelated) distributions `X` and `Y`. Under the null hypothesis, all possible permutations of the elements in `y` are equally likely. By computing the statistic under all possible permutations, we can compute the exact probability of getting a test statistic as extreme as the one that was actually observed.

For your data:

```py
from scipy import stats
x, y = [1, 2, 3], [1, 5, 7]
pearsonr(x, y, method=stats.PermutationMethod())
# PearsonRResult(statistic=0.9819805060619655, pvalue=0.3333333333333333)
```

For larger samples, the number of possible permutations is too large, so a randomized test is performed.

The comment about the p-value only being meaningful for such large samples has been removed in recent version of the documentation. For samples of size 500, the p-values match quite closely (subject to the stochastic nature of the randomized test), even though technically the specific null hypotheses of the two versions of the test are slightly different.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(2348923589435)
x, y = rng.random((2, 20))
stats.pearsonr(x, y)
# PearsonRResult(statistic=0.17895011346631318, pvalue=0.45031837813125064)
stats.pearsonr(x, y, method=stats.PermutationMethod(random_state=rng))
# PearsonRResult(statistic=0.17895011346631318, pvalue=0.4412)
```

However, it doesn't take nearly such large samples to get similar agreement. For instance, for each sample size 4-30, we can generate data for which the p-value produced by `pearsonr` with the default `method` is 0.05, then compare against the p-value produced by the permutation test.

```py
# it would be better to compare the null distributions directly,
# but this is easier without digging into the implementations
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats, optimize

rng = np.random.default_rng(2348923589435)
ns = np.arange(4, 31)
diffs = []
for n in ns:
    x = rng.random(size=n)
    d = rng.normal(size=n)
    res = optimize.root_scalar(lambda c: stats.pearsonr(x, x + c*d).pvalue - 0.05, 
                               bracket=(0, 10))
    y = x + res.root*d
    _, p1 = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
    _, p2 = stats.pearsonr(x, y, method=stats.PermutationMethod())
    diffs.append(np.abs(p2 - p1))

plt.plot(ns, diffs)
```

[image]

For any sample larger than 10, the two appear to agree quite closely.
For more information, see the [Resampling and Monte Carlo Methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/resampling.html) tutorial.