# how can I calculate correlation between all possible rows

Tags: python

I have a very large data in xls . A small portion of it is shown below

```
 Name    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
    A   2   2   2   1   2
    Ab  10  10  9   1   10
    AC  14  7   1   2   14
    AD  5   1   1   1   5
    AF  14  14  11  1   14
    Ag  3   3   3   1   3
    Qn  7   7   7   3   7
    Ah  35  3   3   1   35
```

I want to calculated all possible combination of rows correlation coefficient 
for example, Row 1 and Row 2, Row 1 and Row3 ...

The output I like to have like this

```
Name1   Name2     Correlation Coef
A       Ab    
A       AC
.          .
.          .
.          .
```

i found this one but I could not figure out how to use it 
[Calculating Pearson correlation and significance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949226/calculating-pearson-correlation-and-significance-in-python)

This solution is giving an answer but the problem is that I cannot make the output I want 
http://lilithelina.tumblr.com/post/135265946959/data-analysis-pearson-correlation-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your data as a pandas dataframe (let's say, `df`). Call `df.T.corr().unstack().reset_index()`. `.unstack()` builds a hierarchical index, `.reset_index()` converts it into columns, and `.T` correlates rows instead of columns.

```
results = df.T.corr().unstack().reset_index(name="corr")
print(results)
#   level_0 level_1      corr
#0   A1L020  A1L020  1.000000
#1   A1L020  A1X283  0.993933
#2   A1L020  A2A3N6  0.499363
#3   A1L020  A2RTX5  0.408248
#....
results.to_csv("some_file.csv")
```

Comment: Added `.unstack()`.

Comment: Just did - and changed column names.

Comment: You must save you data as CSV, not as XLS: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Added saving to CSV.

Comment: Whe you read a CVS file, you clearly should use `read_csv()`.

Comment: read_csv() has tons of options http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html You may need to find those that work for you.

Comment: Works for me: `df=pd.read_csv('data.csv',index_col=0); del df.index.name`.

Comment: I am very sure that with some effort you can do it on your own. Just read documentation for `.corr()`.

Comment: You have to do it three times, because it's three different matrices. You can `pd.join()` them later, if you want.