# Calculate correlation coefficient by row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the correlation coefficient like [how can I calculate correlation between all possible rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194203/how-can-i-calculate-correlation-between-all-possible-rows)

My code
import pandas as pd

```
d = {'Name': ['A', 'B','C'], 'v1': [1,3, 4], 'v2': [3,2, 4], 'v3': [3,9 ,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
result = df.T.corr().unstack().reset_index(name="corr")
```

but it shows the error IndexError: list index out of range.

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need initially to ensure *Name* is an index so transpose works
2. after doing `corr()` you need to rename X axis
3. finally you need to rename your columns after `reset_index()`

```
d = {'Name': ['A', 'B','C'], 'v1': [1,3, 4], 'v2': [3,2, 4], 'v3': [3,9 ,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index("Name")
result = df.T.corr()
result.columns.set_names("NameX", inplace=True)
result = result.unstack().to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns={"Name":"NameY",0:"corr"})
```

**output**

```
NameX NameY      corr
    A     A  1.000000
    A     B  0.381246
    A     C -0.500000
    B     A  0.381246
    B     B  1.000000
    B     C -0.991241
    C     A -0.500000
    C     B -0.991241
    C     C  1.000000
```