# Why correlation of two matrix return nan?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics

Consider the following code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
A = np.ones([5,5])
B = np.ones([5,5])
pearsonr(A.flatten(), B.flatten())
```

now my question is why last line of code returns:

```
(nan, 1.0)
```

Comment: What would you expect it to be ?

Comment: pearsonr returns Pearson's correlation coefficient, "2-tailed p-value". Given the shape of distribution it will be NaN one side.

Comment: I just like to know what the reason behind the `nan`.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code it's giving me following error. Are you not getting this error?

```
    In [6]:runfile('C:/Users/a*/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/a*/.spyder-py3')
    (nan, 1.0)
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:3029:  
  RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
      r = r_num / r_den
    C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:5084:  
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
      x = np.where(x < 1.0, x, 1.0)  # if x > 1 then return 1.0
```

When I dig deeper by opening `stats.py`, in `peasronr` function, It appears that the value of `r_den` is equal to zero, which is causing zero division error for value or `r` (Pearson’s correlation coefficient) on line line 2558 and hence `r = NaN` in the code.

Ideally r needs to be zero since correlation between the two identical sets (having identical data) is zero.

You can try out using your own function for similar data as below.
Sourced from [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949226/calculating-pearson-correlation-and-significance-in-python)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
import warnings

def pearsonr(X, Y):
    ''' Takes X & Y as numpy array
       returms Pearson Correlation Coefficient 
    '''
    # Normalise X and Y
    X -= X.mean(0)
    Y -= Y.mean(0)
    # Standardise X and Y
    X /= X.std(0)
    Y /= Y.std(0)
    # Compute mean product
    return np.mean(X*Y)

A = np.ones([5,5]).flatten()
B = np.ones([5,5]).flatten()
print pearsonr(A, B)
```

Still gives exact same as error as `stats.py` `pearsonr` function.
Also notice that return value for **r = NaN**.

```
 In [7]: runfile('C:/Users/a*/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/a*/.spyder-py3')
nan
C:/Users/a*/.spyder-py3/temp.py:14:   
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  X /= X.std(0)
C:/Users/amandr/.spyder-py3/temp.py:15:  
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  Y /= Y.std(0)
```

You can override the warning by catching it using `try - except` to return zero for `r` value in case of identical values.

More on Pearson's correlation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) and [here](http://www.statsoft.com/Textbook/Statistics-Glossary/P/button/p#Pearson%20Correlation).

Comment: I am from Python 3.5.2. @Anil_M

Comment: Updated reply with python 3.6  results. Got same error. And irrespective of python version the explanation holds good.