# How can I use any classifier to classify my data with each data point consisting of a set of floating values?

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, dna-sequence

I have data in this format-

[0.266465   0.9203907  1.007363   ... 0.         0.09623989 0.39632136]

It is the value of the first row and first column.

It is the value of the second column of the first row:

[0.9042176  1.135085   1.2988662  ... 0.         0.13614458 0.28000486]

I have 2200 such rows and I want to train a classifier to identify that if the two set of values are similar or not?

P.S.- These are extracted feature vector values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume relation between two extracted feature vectors to be linear, you could try using **Pearson correlation**:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

list1 = np.random.random(100)
list2 = np.random.random(100)

pearsonr(list1, list2)
```

An example output is:

```
(0.0746901299996632, 0.4601843257734832)
```

Where first value refers to correlation (7%), the second to its significance (with > 0,05 you accept the null hypothesis that the correlation is insignificant at significance level alfa = 5%). And if vectors are correlated, they are be in a way similar. More about the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949226/calculating-pearson-correlation-and-significance-in-python).

Also, I came across **Normalized Cross-Correlation** that is used for identifying similarity between pictures (not an expert, so rather check [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28322/python-normalized-cross-correlation-to-measure-similarites-in-2-images)).

Comment: thanks man, this idea helps, also one another way of doing it could be which i found out is by subtracting those two vectors and storing the result and then training the result on a svm.