# Calculate pearson correlation in python

Tags: python, iteration, correlation

I have 4 columns "Country, year, GDP, CO2 emissions"

I want to measure the pearson correlation between GDP and CO2emissions for each country.

The country column has all the countries in the world and the year has the values "1990, 1991, ...., 2018".

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating Pearson correlation and significance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949226/calculating-pearson-correlation-and-significance-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `groupby` grouped with `corr()` as your aggregation function:

```
country = ['India','India','India','India','India','China','China','China','China','China']
Year = [2018,2017,2016,2015,2014,2018,2017,2016,2015,2014]
GDP = [100,98,94,64,66,200,189,165,134,130]
CO2 = [94,96,90,76,64,180,172,150,121,117]
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':country,'Year':Year,'GDP':GDP,'CO2':CO2})
print(df.groupby('country')[['GDP','CO2']].corr()
```

If we work this output a bit we can go to something fancier:

```
df_corr = (df.groupby('country')['GDP','CO2'].corr()).drop(columns='GDP').drop('CO2',level=1).rename(columns={'CO2':'Correlation'})
df_corr = df_corr.reset_index().drop(columns='level_1').set_index('country',drop=True)
print(df_corr)
```

Output:

```
         Correlation
country             
China       0.999581
India       0.932202
```

Comment: Thank you so much 
I will apply the same principle but using the pearson correlation to get the P-value with the correlation coefficient

Comment: Yes, you can create an extra column with the `P-value` using `pearsonr` from `scipy.stats`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want to have the pearson coef for each country. Using `pearsonr` you can loop through and create a dictionary for each country.

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1":["value 1", "value 1","value 1","value 1","value 2", "value 2", "value 2", "value 2"], 
              "column2":[1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3],
             "column3":[10,30,50, 60, 80, 10, 90, 20],
             "column4":[1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 5, 2, 3]})


results = {}
for country in df.column1.unique():
    results[country] = {}
    pearsonr_value = pearsonr(df.loc[df["column1"]== country, "column3"],df.loc[df["column1"] == country, "column4"])
    results[country]["pearson"] = pearsonr_value[0]
    results[country]["pvalue"] = pearsonr_value[0]

print(results["value 1"])
#{'pearson': 1.0, 'pvalue': 1.0}

print(results["value 2"])
#{'pearson': 0.09258200997725514, 'pvalue': 0.09258200997725514}
```

Comment: Thank you so much 
That is exactly what I wanted 
Many thanks

Comment: @MustafaAdel If it answers your question, could you please accept and upvote the answer? Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not vote. Thank you so much for your help. 
I will try it and let you know how it went 
I am new to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thank you @Celius it worked and gave me the results i wanted.