# How can I check a correlation between having a category and not having category?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I have a machine learning project for predicting card approvals, based on application records. There are several columns in my dataset, categorical feature "Job" with some missing values (around 25%). My target variable called `approval_status` is binary and has only 2 values ('Yes' / 'No').

Logically, a person, who has a missing job field, can be considered as unemployed, hence a less reliable client, rather than the one that has it filled up.

How can I check whether there is some underlying correlation between having this "Job" feature empty or not and how it affects my target variable?

Is there some statistical tests that might be applicable in this situation?

Short description:

Job's missing values - ~25% (nominal)

Approval Status: ('Yes' / 'No') (nominal)

Answer (score 0):

May you find an interesting [Pearson correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient). It compares direction and likeness of two variables. Here it's in Python:

*[Calculating Pearson correlation and significance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949226/calculating-pearson-correlation-and-significance-in-python)*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may be useful information, just a heads-up that link-only answers are [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413510/11810933), and often even deleted by Moderators on Stack Exchange sites since [they aren't considered complete "answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  It's best to include the relevant portions of the link, or at least a summary, in your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks for reference! I'll check this out