# In python, How do we find the Correlation Coefficient between two matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, correlation

I have got two matrices say, T1 and T2 each of size mxn. I want to find the correlation coefficient between two matrices
So far I haven't used any built-in library function for it. I am doing the following steps for it:
First I calculate the mean of the two matrices as:

```
M1 = T1.mean()
M2 = T2.mean()
```

and then I subtract the mean from the corresponding matrices as:

```
A = np.subtract(T1, M1)
B = np.subtract(T2, M2)
```

where np is the numpy library and A and B are the resulting matrices after doing the subtraction.
Now , I calculate the correlation coefficent as:

```
alpha = np.sum(A*B) / (np.sqrt((np.sum(A))*np.sum(B)))
```

However, the value i get is far greater than 1 and in not meaningful at all. It should be in between 0 and 1 to get some meaning out of it.
I have also tried to make use absolute values of matrix A and B, but that also did'nt work.
I also tried to use :

```
np.sum(np.dot(A,B.T)) instead of np.sum(A*B)
```

in the numerator , but that also didn't work.
Edit1:
This is the formula that I intend to calculate:
 [image: This image shows the actual formula to be calculated]

In this image, C is one of the matrices and T is another one.
'u' is the mean symbol.

Can somebody tell me where actually i am doing the mistake.

Comment: Do you want the correlation between the same row in each matrix?

Comment: Or do you want just get the correlation between all values in `A` and all values in `B`? If so, just flatten both matrices into vectors and calculate the regular correlation coefficient

Comment: Please see the edit1 to give more insight into the problem

Comment: Not 100% sure about this, but I think that `np.sum(A*B)` might actually do something else than what is shown in the formula. I guess that the first is calculating the sum of all elements after multiplying the two matrices, whereas the latter is summing up the multiplication of every single pair of values. Maybe you can check that with two very simple 2x2 matrices?

Comment: To make sure you're understood, you could give a small example input for `T1` and `T2`, your expected output, and what you've gotten so far.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0.1, .32, .2, 0.4, 0.8], [.23, .18, .56, .61, .12]])
y = np.array([[2,4,0.1, .32, .2],[1,3,.23, .18, .56]])
pearson = np.corrcoef(x,y)
print(pearson)
```

Comment: it gives back a matrix, but I need a number, a scalar value.

Comment: Could you find any solution?

Comment: you can get the scalar value from two vectors in np.corrcoef(x,y) by taking the [0,1] element

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425439/why-does-corrcoef-return-a-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this function is doing what I intend for:

```
def correlation_coefficient(T1, T2):
    numerator = np.mean((T1 - T1.mean()) * (T2 - T2.mean()))
    denominator = T1.std() * T2.std()
    if denominator == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        result = numerator / denominator
        return result
```

The calculation of numerator seems to be tricky here which doesn't exactly reflect the formula shown in the above image and denominator is just the product of standard deviations of the two images.
However, the result does make a sense now as the result lies only in between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

From the way the problem is described in the OP, the matrices are treated as arrays, so one could simply flatten them:

```
x = T1.flatten()
y = T2.flatten()
```

One could then use either the [builtin numpy function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) proposed by @AakashMakwana:

```
import numy as np
r = np.corrcoef(x, y)[0,1]
```

***Remark:** Note that without flattening this solution would produce the matrix of pairwise correlations.*

Alternatively, one could use the [equivalent `scipy` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html):

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
r = pearsonr(x,y)[0]
```

Scipy additionally provides possibility of calculating Spearman correlation coefficient (`spearmanr(x,y)[0]`) or Kendall tau (`kendalltau(x,y)[0]`).