# numpy.corrcoeff() MemoryError

Tags: numpy, vector, correlation

Can't understand MemoryError I get using numpy.corrcoeff() to find correlation coefficient between 2 vectors `smin` & `smax` as following:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as rn
r=0.01
sigma=0.2
T=1
K=1
N=252
h=T/N 
M  = 50000
Z = rn.randn(M,N)
S=np.ones((M,N+1))
smax=np.ones((M,1))
smin=np.ones((M,1))
for i in range(0,N):
    S[:,i+1]=S[:,i]*(np.exp((r-(sigma**2)/2)*h+sigma*Z[:,i]*np.sqrt(h)))
for j in range(0,M):
    smax[j,:]=np.exp(-r*T)*(np.max(S[j,:])>K)*(np.max(S[j,:])-K)
    smin[j,:]=np.exp(-r*T)*(np.min(S[j,:])<K)*(K-np.min(S[j,:]))
c=np.corrcoef(smax,smin)
print(c)
```

if there is another way to find correlation coeff.,like using pandas it's also good.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of your arrays here is what is the problem. The [function documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) states that x is a "1-D or 2-D array containing multiple variables and observations. Each row of x represents a variable, and each column a single observation of all those variables." and that y is an additional set of variables and observations. So this is trying to allocate an array of size (10000, 10000), which is huge.

If you just want to calculate the pearson correlation coefficient between two one dimensional vectors, you can use a much simpler formula than what is implemented here. This documentation has the formula I am referring to.

https://hydroerr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/HydroErr.HydroErr.pearson_r.html#HydroErr.HydroErr.pearson_r

But to be able to still use the numpy version you need to pass in the observations and predictions in the same parameter x, and x and y need to be 1D arrays.

```
import numpy as np

simulated_array = np.random.rand(50000)
observed_array = np.random.rand(50000)

c = np.corrcoef([simulated_array, observed_array])[1, 0]
```

More explanation about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3425548/8749168).