# numpy.corrcoef() doubts about return value

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, correlation, pearson-correlation

I need the Pearson's correlation coefficient between two matrix X,Y.
If I run the code `corr=numpy.corrcoef(X,Y)` my output is a matrix with correlation coefficients.
However I need a single value to represent the correlation between two matrix.

I just saw on this kennytm's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425439/why-does-corrcoef-return-a-matrix) that to have one value I should write `numpy.corrcoef(X,Y)[1,0]`.

This solution works but I don't understand what that numbers inside square brackets mean and why adding them I have as outcome one single value.

I'm interpreting 1 and 0 as limits of the coefficient but what's happen to all the coefficients inside the matrix? 
What type of operation is computed on them to obtain a single value?
If I change numbers inside square brackets for example `[1,-1]`([correlation, anticorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)) the value of `corr` change so I'm confused which numbers I should use inside brackets.

Comment: The `[1,0]` is just the way indexing works in Python. When you execute `corrcoef(X,Y)`, the output is an array of size determined by the size of your input arrays. To access a certain element of such array you use the square brackets. More generally, `[i,j]` refers to the element in the i-th row and j-th column. The `-1` is used to index the last element along a certain axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`numpy.corrcoef` returns a matrix containing the correlation coefficient for every pair of rows. So for example, `numpy.corrcoef(A,B)`  for `A.shape=(3,3)` and `B.shape=(3,3)` will return a `(6,6)` matrix since there are 36 row combinations.  Note it's a symmetric matrix since it returns both correlations for (e.g.) `A[1],B[1]` (index `[1,4]`) and `B[1],A[1]` (index `[4,1]`). When you have two 1-D arrays, you get a `(2,2)` matrix: the correlation of the first array with itself `[0,0]`, the correlation of the first array with the second array `[0,1]`, the correlation of the second array with the first array `[1,0]` and the correlation of the second array with itself `[1,1]`.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(low=0, high=99, size=(3,3))
B = np.random.randint(low=0, high=99, size=(3,3))
C = np.corrcoef(A,B)
print(C[1,4]==np.corrcoef(A[1],B[1])[0,1]) # True
```

If you want the 2-D correlation (like correlation between images), flatten the 2-D arrays, so you obtain a single row for every array. Then, the element `[0,1]` or `[1,0]` of that correlation matrix will be how do the 2-D arrays correlate to each other fully.

```
print(np.corrcoef(A.flatten(), B.flatten())[0,1])
```